# Update cross object field

Tags: workflow, process-builder, customization

I want to update a field on all the campaign members when a field on the related contact is updated in Salesforce . Both the fields (on contact and campaign member are standard Fields) .

How can we achieve this without using triggers in Salesforce?

Comment: use Process builder.

Comment: @Tushar , can you help me build the process , I tried this at my end but that did not work.

Comment: what did not work for you?

Answer (score 2):

The Process Builder is a workflow tool that helps you easily automate your business processes by providing a powerful and user-friendly graphical representation of your process as you build it.

You can use the more powerful and flexible Process Builder to perform the same actions as workflow. With the Process Builder, you can:

- Create a record
- **Update any related record—not just the record or its parent**
- Use a quick action to create a record, update a record, or log a call
- Launch a flow—you can’t schedule this action with workflow
- Send an email
- Post to Chatter
- Submit for approval

[See Process Builder example](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/business_process_automation/process_builder)

You need to select primary Object as Contact, add the criteria to execute. In the next step you need to add immediate Action. The action will be "Update Related records". This will show CampaignMember object as well.

You process will be like this.

[image]